# How to use ArrayFormula with my Sum fuctions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Google Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ldOqGgkPq9FrOSOODcxc9SKPGF434M96K27k_6JcCs/edit?usp=sharing)

I am new to Google sheet and can't figure a good way to do this.
I have tried doing the manual addition way, I got the idea, but am clueless on how to use in my own function :

```
= ArrayFormula(SUM 
(Product (SUMIF(F2:L,"=4"),p_4),
 Product (SUMIF(F2:L,"=3"),p_3), 
 Product (SUMIF(F2:L,"=2"),p_2),
 Product (SUMIF(F2:L,"=1"),p_1)))
```

Also, I am doing this so that the data from Google Form can get auto calculated.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IFNA(F2:L*
 VLOOKUP(F2:L, 'Price Sheet'!A:B, 2, ), 0), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F:L), 1, 1, ))))
```

[image]